# Nuspec buildAction not applying to contentFiles

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec, nuget-spec

I've been recently trying to create a *.nuspec* file that attaches a *.dll* file as an Embedded Resource. To do so, I've used the `contentFiles` tag on `metadata`, setting the `buildAction="EmbeddedResource"`, as described in the section **Example contentFiles section** on [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec).

Below you can see my *.nuspec* file content:

```
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>MyPackage</id>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        <title>MyPackage</title>
        <authors>Matias G Henschel</authors>
        <owners>Matias G Henschel</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>My package description</description>
        <copyright>2017</copyright>
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="myDllFile.dll" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="content\myDllFile.dll" target="contentFiles" />
    </files>
</package>
```

This package correctly copies the file inside the target project, but it **doesn't apply the Build Action** to it, which is crucial for me.

I've also tried using a *.targets* file, with no success.

If you want to see more, I've also created an [Issue on the GitHub page](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6000).

PS: IMHO, both documentation on contentFiles and .targets files require some rework, they aren't clear enough and .targets' lacks examples.

Answer (score 2):

You also need a file entry to actually copy the file to the correct `contentFiles` folder:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    …
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/MyEmbeddedFile.txt" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="path/to/MyEmbeddedFile.txt" target="contentFiles/any/any/MyEmbeddedFile.txt" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Note that this will only work in NuGet 3.3+ with `project.json` based projects and NuGet 4+ for `PackageReference` based projects. For projects using this package via `packages.config`, you will still need to add the file to the `content` folder and add a custom target to make it the right item type.

Comment: The file is as recommended and it doesn't work. The only detail is the *any/any* folder structure, which I tried with no success. For reference: I'm using Nuget 4.1.

Comment: just to be clear, which kind of project are you installing this into? the embedded resource won't show up in the solution explorer, you'll need to open the exe/dll in dotPeek / ILSpy or sth. also note that you need to clear your NuGet cache unless you always increase the version number on every try using `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`

Comment: I'm trying to add it to a Class Library. The version is not a problem, I'm setting it manually and I'm able to install the package correctly. It just doesn't add it the correct way (Embedded Resource). I did use ILSpy to check if the file was in there but no resource was attached. When I manually set it to Embedded Resource, the file showed up in ILSpy.

Comment: Is the consuming project using `ProjectReference` or `packages.config`? because contentFiles doesn't work with `packages.config`

Comment: It uses `packages.config`... But how would I work around it? It should work just like any other NuGet package...

Comment: It doesn't. `contentFiles` is only for `ProjectReference` or `project.json`.

Comment: If I can't use `contentFiles`, what should I use? A `.targets` file? (couldn't figure it out how to) I only need a `.dll` file as an Embedded Resource. That's all.